# ulogin получить данные

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

всем привет, добавил плагин uLogin, пытаюсь сделать регистрацию пользователей через соц сети с отправкой на мою почту данных о пользователе
добавил на страницу такой код для регистрации

```
   <div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=buttons;fields=first_name,last_name,phone,email;">
    <img src="vkontakte.png" data-uloginbutton = "vkontakte"/>
    <img src="facebook.png" data-uloginbutton = "facebook"/>
</div>
```

а как мне теперь получить данные о пользователе, чтобы я смог использовать функцию mail()

Comment: У них на сайте есть плагин для WP и кучи других cms/форумов. И навряд ли к вам кто пойдет с таким набором обязательных полей `fields=first_name,last_name,phone,email` :)

Comment: Как уже написали выше, у uLogin есть плагин для WP, весьма неплохой. При авторизации/регистрации пользователя через соц. сеть создаётся его профиль в WP, цепляйте хук на типовое событие создания пользователя и отправляйте всё, что вам нужно. Лучше с использованием функции `wp_mail()`